# bluetooth connection in android (server and client wrong)

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, server, client

i use these codes but Bluetooth socket never created.
i have two phones, SAMSUNG galaxy S5 and Huwaii. i run server code on Huwaii and client code in galaxy but state string in both is "waiting", that means never can create Bluetooth socket, these codes are exactly copied from GOOGLE android Tutriol and I don't know what wrong is.

myClientCode is this :

```
public class BluetoothActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
public static final int    MESSAGE_READ    = 1;
TextView                   state;
BluetoothAdapter           btadaptor;
ListView                   list;
ArrayAdapter<String>       array;
Set<BluetoothDevice>       btarray;
ArrayList<String>          pairedDevices;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;

IntentFilter               filter;
BroadcastReceiver          receiver;
Handler                    mHandler        = new Handler() {

                                               @Override
                                               public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                                                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                   super.handleMessage(msg);
                                                   switch (msg.what) {
                                                       case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                                                           //Do something
                                                           ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                                                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connected", 0).show();
                                                           String s = "SSSSSS";
                                                           connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                                                           break;
                                                       case MESSAGE_READ:
                                                           byte[] readbuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                                                           String string = new String(readbuf);

                                                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sus message", 0).show();
                                                           break;
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           };

public static final UUID   MY_UUID         = UUID.fromString("0efe5656-27d7-11e6-b67b-9e71128cae77");


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    init();
    if (btadaptor == null)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bluetooth not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
    {
        if ( !btadaptor.enable())
        {
            startbt();
        }

        getPairedDevice();
        startActivity();
    }

}


private void startActivity() {
    btadaptor.cancelDiscovery();
    btadaptor.startDiscovery();
}


private void getPairedDevice() {
    btarray = btadaptor.getBondedDevices();
    if (btarray.size() > 0)
    {
        for (BluetoothDevice bt: btarray)
        {
            pairedDevices.add(bt.getName());
            //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bt.getName(), 0).show();

        }
    }

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you need to turn on the bluetooth to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            finish();
        }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


private void init() {
    state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    state.setText("waitingforlist");
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    list.setAdapter(array);
    btadaptor = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context contex, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
            {

                BluetoothDevice bt = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                devices.add(bt);
                String s = "";
                for (int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++) {
                    if (bt.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))) {
                        s = "(PAIRED)";
                    }
                }
                array.add(bt.getName() + s + "\n" + bt.getAddress());

            }

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
}


protected void startbt() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    if (btadaptor.isDiscovering()) {
        btadaptor.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), array.getItem(arg2), 0).show();
    if (array.getItem(arg2).contains("PAIRED")) {
        //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", 0).show();

        BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedDevice.getAddress(), 0).show();

        ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
        state.setText("CreatedThread");
        connectThread.start();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is not Paried", 0).show();

}


public class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;


    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
        mmSocket = tmp;
        state.setText(device.getName());
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        //     btadaptor.cancelDiscovery();
        //      state.setText("DONE RUN2");

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            state.setText("waiting");

            mmSocket.connect();
            state.setText("connected");
        }
        catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException closeException) {}
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        //  manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }
}


/** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
/*       public void cancel() {
           try {
               mmSocket.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e) {}
       }
   }
*/

///////////////////////
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream     mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream    mmOutStream;


    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer; // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                buffer = new byte[1024];
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }

}
}
```

myServerCode is this :

```
public class BluetoothActivity extends Activity {

protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
public static final int    MESSAGE_READ    = 1;
Button                     bt;
BluetoothAdapter           btadaptor;
TextView                   state;
Handler                    mHandler        = new Handler() {

                                               @Override
                                               public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                                                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                   super.handleMessage(msg);
                                                   switch (msg.what) {
                                                       case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                                                           //Do something
                                                           ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                                                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connected", 0).show();
                                                           String s = "SSSSSS";
                                                           connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                                                           break;
                                                       case MESSAGE_READ:
                                                           byte[] readbuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                                                           String string = new String(readbuf);

                                                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sus message", 0).show();
                                                           break;
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           };

public static final UUID   MY_UUID         = UUID.fromString("0efe5656-27d7-11e6-b67b-9e71128cae77");


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    init();
    if (btadaptor == null)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bluetooth not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
    {
        if ( !btadaptor.enable())
        {
            startbt();
        }

        startActivity();
        startDiscovering();
        OnClickListener temp = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AcceptThread acceptThread = new AcceptThread();
                state.setText("THreadCreAted");
                acceptThread.start();
            }
        };
        bt.setOnClickListener(temp);
    }

}


private void startActivity() {
    btadaptor.cancelDiscovery();
    btadaptor.startDiscovery();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you need to turn on the bluetooth to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


private void init() {
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    state.setText("START");
    btadaptor = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}


private void startDiscovering() {
    Intent discoverableIntent = new
            Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    state.setText("StartDiscovering");
}


protected void startbt() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}


private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;


    public AcceptThread() {
        btadaptor.cancelDiscovery();
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
        // because mmServerSocket is final
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = btadaptor.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("MYAPP", MY_UUID);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        state.setText("runStart");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                state.setText("WAIITING");
                state.setText("WAIITING2");

                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                state.setText("ConnectionREquesRECIEVED");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {

                state.setText("ACCEPTED");
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                //         manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                try {
                    mmServerSocket.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}


private void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket mmSocket2) {

}


///////////////////////
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream     mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream    mmOutStream;


    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer; // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                buffer = new byte[1024];
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }


    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
}
```

is any body know whats wrong ?
or can anybody show me very simple code (both server and client) Bluetooth socket just for connection and sending message ?